# if url statement

Tags: php

```
<?php
$error = 'error';
$check = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($check == "/bleachers.php") 
{
    echo 'bleachers';
} 
elseif($check == 'runners.php') 
{ 
    echo 'runners'; 
}
else
{ 
    echo $error;
}
?>
```

I'm trying to figure out why this is not working. I am trying to echo out a text based on the url of a website. If the url is site.com/bleachers.php echo bleachers
elseif site.com/runners.php echo runners else echo error.

I type in the url `site.com/bleachers` and error prints out instead.

Comment: Have you used `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` to see what it actually is? What server software?

Comment: Try `echo $check;` so you can actually see what you're doing wrong and stop guessing. Don't make any assumptions when you're debugging. Always debug with your brain switched on.

Comment: Debugging 101: when you have two things that you expect to be equal but the program tells you are not, usually the next step is to print them and see what it's talking about for yourself.

Comment: Perhaps it's more useful to do `else echo ("error " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` instead, so you can figure out what you're supposed to check for. I suspect, by the way, you want to look at `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` instead; see [the list of all `$_SERVER` indices](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for more info.

Comment: try <?php 
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?> maybe you better use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URL']

Comment: Who up-voted this, and why? o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with changing:

```
else echo $error;
```

into:

```
else echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

this should help you determine what should actually be in the if statements.

Comment: saw where i messed up thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may be running on IIS, where the `REQUEST_URI` environmental variable is not set.

[You can add it yourself](http://davidwalsh.name/iis-php-server-request_uri).

Also, you should get into the habit of debugging code yourself. Start at the beginning here by using...

```
var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

It it is indeed set, ensure it contains the correct strings you are trying to match.